# Extracting numbers from text with stringr and regex in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a problem where I'm trying to extract numbers from a string containing text and numbers and then create two new columns showing the Min and Max of the numbers.

For example, I have one column and a string of data like this:

```
Text
Section 12345.01 to section 12345.02
```

And I want to create two new columns from the data in the Text column, like this:

```
Min        Max   
12345.01   12345.02
```

I'm using dplyr and stringr with regex, but the regex only extracts the first occurence of the pattern (first number).

```
df%>%dplyr::mutate(SectionNum = stringr::str_extract(Text, "\\d+.\\d+"))
```

If I try to use the `stringr::str_extract_all` function. It seems to extract both occurence of the pattern, but it creates a list in the tibble, which I find is a real hassle. So I'm stuck on the first step, just trying to get the numbers out into their own columns.

Can anyone recommend the most efficient way to do this? Ideally I'd like to extract the numbers from the string, convert them to numbers `as.numeric` and then run `min()` and `max()` functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `extract` from `tidyr`. `extract` turns each regex capture group into its own column. `convert = TRUE` is convenient in that it coerces the resulting columns to the best format. `remove = FALSE` can be used if we want to keep the original column. The last `mutate` is optional to make sure that the first number extracted is really the minimum:

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  extract(Text, c("Min", "Max"), "([\\d.]+)[^\\d.]+([\\d.]+)", convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Min = pmap_dbl(., min),
         Max = pmap_dbl(., max))
```

**Output:**

```
       Min      Max
1 12345.02 12345.03
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Text = structure(1L, .Label = "Section 12345.03 to section 12345.02", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), .Names = "Text")
```

Comment: Great answer! (+1). First I've seen the `tidyr::extract()` function, and it's awesome. Although, I will say that this could run into problems for OP if the min and max are not predictably the first and second matches.

Comment: I'll note that this approach is concise but works only when there are just the two numbers in the `Text` column, and they are ordered with the first being smaller. Unclear from OP whether this is the case

Comment: Thanks for this solution. The `tidyr::extract()` function is really cool. It's also the first I've seen it. Typically the section numbers will be in the correct order, but it's possible there could be a situation where they aren't.

Comment: @RyanMinaker All we needed to do is add the last `mutate` step to make sure that the order does not mess up the columns. See my update.

Answer (score 5):

Using some other `tidyverse` tools, you can either approach this by `unnest`ing the list-column and using `group_by` and `summarise` semantics (the more `dplyr` way), or you can just deal with the list-col as-is and use `map_dbl` to extract the max and min from each row (a more `purrr` way). My benchmarks have `map_dbl` about 7 times faster than `unnest` and `dplyr`, and about 15% faster than `extract`, though this is only on the one row.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  Text = c("Section 12345.01 to section 12345.02")
)

df %>%
  mutate(SectionNum = str_extract_all(Text, "\\d+\\.\\d+")) %>%
  unnest %>%
  group_by(Text) %>%
  summarise(min = min(as.numeric(SectionNum)), max = max(as.numeric(SectionNum)))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   Text                                    min    max
#>   <chr>                                 <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Section 12345.01 to section 12345.02 12345. 12345.

df %>%
  mutate(
    SectionNum = str_extract_all(Text, "\\d+\\.\\d+"),
    min = map_dbl(SectionNum, ~ min(as.numeric(.x))),
    max = map_dbl(SectionNum, ~ max(as.numeric(.x)))
  )
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   Text                                 SectionNum    min    max
#>   <chr>                                <list>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Section 12345.01 to section 12345.02 <chr [2]>  12345. 12345.
```

Created on 2018-09-24 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: My benchmark shows otherwise. `extract` is twice as fast.

Answer (score 2):

There have already been answers which say how to accomplish your final goal as asked in the question, but just to address the question of how you can find the first or second match using the `stringr` package, you can use the `str_match` function, and specify the specific match you are interested in by referring to the column of `str_match`.

```
library(stringr)

Text <- "Section 12345.01 to section 12345.02"

str_match(Text, "^[^0-9.]*([0-9.]*)[^0-9.]*([0-9.]*)[^0-9.]*$")[2]
#> [1] "12345.01"
str_match(Text, "^[^0-9.]*([0-9.]*)[^0-9.]*([0-9.]*)[^0-9.]*$")[3]
#> [1] "12345.02"
```

Created on 2018-09-24 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).